# UNIX command for replacing within delimiter based on position of the delimiter

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl, cut

I have a input string with `|` [pipe] delimiter and like to replace the empty string 3rd and 5th column by `&` character.

Input File:

```
a a|b b|c c|d d|e e
f f|g g|h h|i i|j j
```

Output File:

```
a a|b b|c&c|d d|e&e
f f|g g|h&h|i i|j&j
```

You can see the space between `cc, ee, hh and jj` is replaced with `&`
I have an alternate solution which involves read file using *while loop* and by using `cut` command based on delimiter and storing it in variable based on position and replacing the space by '&' using `sed` and append all the splitted variable in to one variable and append it in a new file. Is there a single command which can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F\| '{gsub(" ","\\&",$3); gsub(" ","\\&",$5)}1' OFS=\| infile.txt
```

- The `-F\|`, telling 'awk' that fields are delimited by `|` pipe (it's escaped by `\` to shell don't interpret it as [`pipeline stdin`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), we could use `-F"|"` or either `-F'|'`).
- The [`gsub("regexp","replacement"[, INDEX])`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) syntax used to replace `" "` (space) with literal `&` in index (column) `$3` and `$5`, below is showing each Index position based on `|` delimiter.

  ```
  a a|b b|c c|d d|e e
  ^^^|^^^|^^^|^^^|^^^
  $1 |$2 |$3 |$4 |$5
  ```

  Read more about [why we escaped `\\&` there and two times?!](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Gory-Details.html#Gory-Details)
- What is the `1` used at the end in `awk '{...}1'`? it's awk's default action control to print. [read more in details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63891/72456)
- The `OFS=\|` again bring back or print the fields with specified `|` delimiter.

Answer (score 8):

You could do

```
sed 's/\(|[^| ]*\) */\1\&/4;s//\1\&/2'
```

for your example. Explained:

`|[^| ]*` searches for your field separator and all non-spaces in that column. It's grouped with `\(\)` so it can later be copied to the replacement by `\1`. Then one or more whitespaces will get replaced by the `&`, which needs to be escaped in the replacement string. The `4` means to apply this to the fourth occurence which is the fifth column. Then repeat it with `2` for the third column. You don't need to repeat the pattern by giving an empty pattern.

More complicated if there can be more than a single group of spaces in the column or none at all. Then better use a different tool like `awk`.

On the other hand, if you know that there is always one whitespace in each column, do a simple

```
sed 's/ /\&/5;s//\&/3'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
perl -aF'(\|)' -lne 's/\h/&/ for @F[2*2,2*4]; print @F' input_file
```

---

## Results

```
a a|b b|c&c|d d|e&e
f f|g g|h&h|i i|j&j
```

---

## Working

Split the current record on pipe `|` and also include the delimiter in the fields. Hence, the 3rd and 5th fields become 2*2 and 2*4 fields.

For both these fields, we replace the horizontal whitespace `\h` with a literal `&`. When done, just print the fields.