# How to understand the command awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/0.00000/){sub(/0.00000/,++i)}}1' file

Tags: awk

As for this Command:

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/0.00000/){sub(/0.00000/,++i)}}1'
```

I know this command will look for "0.00000" in a file and replace it with an incremental number starting from 1. I understood almost everything except for 'x<=NF' and the number 1 at the end "{sub(/0.00000/,++i)}}1'. Can you enlighten me on these two points, please?

Also, If I want to do the same thing but replacing the match with an incremental number starting from 0, would it be correct to do:

```
awk '{for(x=0;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/0.00000/){sub(/0.00000/,++i)}}1' file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NF` is an internal Awk variable whose value is set to the number of fields in the current record. So

```
for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)
```

is looping over all the fields. The number `1` at the end of the expression is a shorthand way of printing the whole record, making use of the default action when a pattern evaluates "true":

> In an awk rule, either the pattern or the action can be omitted, but
>   not both. If the pattern is omitted, then the action is performed for
>   every input line. If the action is omitted, the default action is to
>   print all lines that match the pattern.<sup>1</sup>

To start the incrementing number from `0` instead of `1`, you can replace the prefix `++i` by postfix `i++`:

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/0.00000/){sub(/0.00000/,i++)}}1'
```

ex.

```
$ echo 'foo 0.00000123 bar' | awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/0.00000/){sub(/0.00000/,++i)}}1'
foo 1123 bar
```

whereas

```
$ echo 'foo 0.00000123 bar' | awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/0.00000/){sub(/0.00000/,i++)}}1'
foo 0123 bar
$
```

---

1. [The GNU Awk User's Guide: 1.3 Some Simple Examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Very-Simple.html)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. For the second part of my question, I would like to start the incrementing number from 0 like 0, 1, 2,...6000 and not from 1 to 0. Is it correct what I proposed?

Comment: @FZJ no, what you proposed would apply the search-and-replace operation to the whole record (`$0`) in addition to each individual field (`$1` to `$NF`)

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case, how can I start the incrementation from 0, please?

Comment: `for(x=0` and so forth.  That is where the start of the loop is defined.

Comment: Regarding the `1` answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth to mention that

```
sub(/0.00000/,i++)
```

will replace the first occurrence in the entire line ($0, the default). By accident, this will also be the occurrence in `$x`. To make it failsafe, and for future application, replace it with

```
sub(/0.00000/,i++, $x)
```