# Sed - find and run command

Tags: sed

I have a file called app.properties like this

```
prop1.value=hi
prop2.value=hello
prop3.url=https://google.com
```

As per my requirement, If I see any `.value` , i need to call an utility function to get the value replaced. just for the example the utility simply multiples the number of chars passed to it * 2.

So, it should become like this.

```
prop1.value=4
prop2.value=10
prop3.url=https://google.com
```

I have done simple find and replacement with sed. Not sure how to call any command to replace the value.

```
  sed -E 's/.value=(.*)/.value=\1/g' app.properties
```

If sed is not correct choice, can you suggest any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="="} $1 ~ /\.value$/ {$2 = 2 * length($2)} 1' app.properties 
prop1.value=4
prop2.value=10
prop3.url=https://google.com
```

If you want something closer to your `sed` approach, then perhaps

```
perl -pe 's/\.value=(.*)/sprintf ".value=%s", 2 * length $1/e' app.properties
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\.value=).*/2 * length $&/e' app.properties
```

Comment: you are genius! Would you explain what does the 1 `{$2 = 2 * length($2)} 1'` do here?

Comment: @RamPrakash please see [what is the meaning of 1 at the end of awk script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script)