# If a given value is in column A, replace the value in column B

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Given the following data:

```
aaa bbb aaa ccc aaa ddd
123 222 aaa aaa bbb ccc
```

If the value in column 4 is "ccc", I want to replace the value in column 6 on the same line with the word "end" using sed or awk.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '$4=="ccc"{ $6="end" }1' file
```

The `1` at the end just prints the current line and is a shortcut for `{ print }` (see [what is the meaning of 1 at the end of awk script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using sed to perform operations on tabular data, but I offer a GNU sed solution anyway, given the question's tag.

```
sed -r 's:^(([^ ]* ){3}ccc [^ ]* )[^ ]*(.*)$:\1end\3:' file
```

I assumed there could be more than 6 columns. If not, then group \3 `(.*)` isn't needed.

As you see the code isn't that readable and error-prone when written/modified, therefore an awk solution for example is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    o=i.strip().split(' ')
    if ( o[3] == "ccc" ):
        o[5]="end"
    print " ".join(o)
```

output

```
aaa bbb aaa ccc aaa end
123 222 aaa aaa bbb ccc
```