# How to do calculation for each row

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv-simple

I had a csv file of data such like that when read into shell:

```
name,income,reward,payment
Jackson,10000,2000,1000
Paul,2500,700,200
Louis,5000,100,1800
```

and I want to find the net earning for each person, use formula: "net = income+reward-payment".

when I used command to do this, it only calculate the first row of data.

```
$ cat data.csv | awk -F ',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) net[i] = $2+$3-$4} END {for (p in total) print p, "net = ", net[p]}' > result.txt
```

How can I do the calculation here?

By the way, the names are not unique, so I try (for loop) to create index for the array [net].

My expected output is:

```
1 Jackson net = 11000
2 Paul net = 3000
3 Louis net = 3300
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR>1 { print $1, $2+$3-$4 }' data.csv 
Jackson,11000
Paul,3000
Louis,3300
```

Or if you want the net appended to the existing data, along with the (updated) header line:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1 {print $0,"net"}; NR>1 {print $0, $2+$3-$4}' data.csv 
name,income,reward,payment,net
Jackson,10000,2000,1000,11000
Paul,2500,700,200,3000
Louis,5000,100,1800,3300
```

Comment: Assuming the CSV is really simple (no escaped commas, etc.)…

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yep.  To parse CSV properly (with quotes and escapes etc), you need a real CSV parser.   Either a tool like `csvkit`, or a CSV-parsing library for perl (e.g. `Text::CSV`) or python (e.g. `csv`) or whatever language you're using.   This answer is only good for simple comma-**delimited** input like in the OP's example, not full CSV.

Answer (score 4):

do in this way:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } { $5=NR>1?$2+$3-$4:"net" }1' infile
name,income,reward,payment,net
Jackson,10000,2000,1000,11000
Paul,2500,700,200,3000
Louis,5000,100,1800,3300
```

---

or having your updated expected output:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{ print NR-1, $1, "net= " $2+$3-$4 }' ifnile
1 Jackson net= 11000
2 Paul net= 3000
3 Louis net= 3300
```

Comment: What is the 1 doing in the `}1` part?

Comment: @nit2qubit read https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63891/72456

Comment: " `1` is the condition, which always evaluates to `true` since it is nonzero. The `action` is omitted, so the default `{print}` is performed."

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

`awk -F',' '{ p[NR] = $1;net[NR] = $2+$3-$4} END {for (i=2;i<=NR;i++) print (i-1), p[i], "net = ", net[i]}' data.csv`

Because this is a `csv` file, `FS = ','` or `-F ','`

Next `p` and `net` arrays created. These are indexed on NR(record numbers).

Then a for loop `(i-1), p[i], "net = ", net[i]` works as you planned.
`for` loop is being started from 2 because first line is header line.

`pipe` in this case is useless use. Anohter thing your loop is good but limit should be `NR` not `NF`.

Comment: @EdMorton Rolled back to revision one. Thanks for pointing out.